# How to style a div so that the table inside gets partially hidden and can be scrolled

Tags: css, scroll, html-table, row

I have a table, and I want to put it inside a div so that the table is only shown until the div's height, and can be scrolled to view the rest of the table. Here is my code:

```css
#listTimes {
  margin-right: 0;
  height: 100px;
}

#timesList table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#timesList table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

#timesList th {
  text-align: left;
}

#session {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  height: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="listTimes">
      <form id="session">
           <select name="sessions" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
             <option value="1">Session 1</option>
             <option value="2">Session 2</option>
             <option value="3">Session 3</option>
             <option value="4">Session 4</option>
             <option value="5">Session 5</option>
           </select>
          </form>
          <br>
          <div id="timesList">
             <!-- This is where the table is -->
             <table>
               <tr>
                 <th>No.</th>
                 <th>foo</th>
                 <th>bar</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <th>1</th>
                 <th>fubar</th>
                 <th>lnrbaaet</th>
               </tr>
             </table>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Right now, the table just appears the way it is. I want to set a height for both the form and the table together, and when I scroll to see the table, the form should follow me. I tried this using height attributes, overflow attributes, but none of them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `overflow-y` property set `height` on `#timesList`

```
 #timesList {
      margin-right: 0;
      height: 100px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

```css
.listTimes {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#timesList {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /* rough width of scrollbar */
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-right: -20px;
}

#timesList table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#timesList table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

#timesList th {
  text-align: left;
}

#session {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  height: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="listTimes">
  <form id="session">
    <select name="sessions" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
             <option value="1">Session 1</option>
             <option value="2">Session 2</option>
             <option value="3">Session 3</option>
             <option value="4">Session 4</option>
             <option value="5">Session 5</option>
           </select>
  </form>
  <br>
  <div id="timesList">
    <!-- This is where the table is -->
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>foo</th>
        <th>bar</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>fubar</th>
        <th>lnrbaaet</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>fubar</th>
        <th>lnrbaaet</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>fubar</th>
        <th>lnrbaaet</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>fubar</th>
        <th>lnrbaaet</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how I hide the scrollbar that appears?

Comment: @Cubetastic Updated. You can use `::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}` however I'm not sure it has support in Firefox or Edge...

Comment: `padding-right: 20px; margin-right: -20px;` Doesn't work, it merely changes the position of the scrollbar. Is there any way to lower the z-index of that alone? And `::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}` works in chrome, but not in firefox, juat like you said.

Comment: Aside from `::-webkit-scrollbar` I don't know of another way to hide the scrollbar. It should work fine, as it does in my snippet. Could you provide a demo of your markup? Maybe it's not working because of something else affecting it

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by "the form should follow me" but I assume you mean it should stay fixed.  In that case you need to add the height and the overflow to the `#timesList` element.  If not, add it to the #listTimes element.

```css
#listTimes {
  margin-right: 0;
  height: 100px;
}
#timesList {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#timesList table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#timesList table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

#timesList th {
  text-align: left;
}

#session {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  height: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="listTimes">
      <form id="session">
           <select name="sessions" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
             <option value="1">Session 1</option>
             <option value="2">Session 2</option>
             <option value="3">Session 3</option>
             <option value="4">Session 4</option>
             <option value="5">Session 5</option>
           </select>
          </form>
          <br>
          <div id="timesList">
             <!-- This is where the table is -->
             <table>
               <tr>
                 <th>No.</th>
                 <th>foo</th>
                 <th>bar</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <th>1</th>
                 <th>fubar</th>
                 <th>lnrbaaet</th>
               </tr>
             </table>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! It totally works! I saw that another working answer has also been posted, and I'm going to accept that, but just for the record, both your answers work. I'm literally just doing this because I can't accept 2 answers. But I upvoted you!